# Android layout : imageview is moving along with edittext

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi, I have a image view and edit text as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:background="#eeeff4" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btextview"
        android:layout_width="280px"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#3B5999"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:text="post it"
        android:textSize="17sp" />



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/username"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#3B5999"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/book" />





    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bedittext"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bedittext"
        android:src="@drawable/myfb"
         android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/bedittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btextview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="say something about this"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true" >
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

when I type in the edittextview multiple line the imageveiw1 also moving along with the edit text, I want the image to be fixed in that position and only the edit text should expand, also how can I make the edittext to get scrolling after 3 lines.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *I type in the edittextview multiple line the imageveiw1 also moving along with the edit text*

because you are setting layout_width="wrap_content" to that edit text, so that if you type one character then image shows next to that char, if you type 2nd char then it moves.. ok? to avoid that you can set fixed with or match_parent to that edittext.

2 . *how can I make the edittext to get scrolling after 3 lines*

just set fixed height to show only three lines and move that edit text into scroll view(this height and width should wrap_content).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the max height of the EditText (android:maxHeight), and set the layout_height of the EditText to wrap_content so it expand till max height